# oracle materialized view parallelism

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing, refresh, materialized-views

I have some doubts about parallelism in materialized views.

Whats the different between using parallelism on query or in refresh?

For example:

```
EXECUTE DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MV_PART_SALES',PARALLELISM=>4);

select /*+ parallel(4) */ * from MV_NAME;
```

What is the best approach for this?

Best Regards,
Macieira

Answer (score 1):

When you specify:

```
EXECUTE DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MV_PART_SALES',PARALLELISM=>4);
```

that means mat view will be UPDATED using parallel degree 4. i.e. DML into underlying table MV_PART_SALES as well as select from underlying query will run in parallel.
When you select from refreshed mat. view as

```
select /*+ parallel(4) */ * from MV_NAME;
```

you enforce parallelism for this particular SQL, i.e. read from materialized results in parallel. These are two different operations - first one is writing, second one is reading.